# Compilation Errors after Maven successfully downloaded Jars

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am new to Maven,and trying to run a tutorial project from the internet.

I have ran Maven `INSTALL` successfully. It downloaded all required JARs.

But still getting compilation errors in the classes.

Please help me, and tell me how the downloaded JARs will be picked up by classes.

Or DO I need to handle in build classpath ? or it will be automatically picked up somehow.

Comment: try project->clean all the projects

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the code you are trying to compile ... or in its dependencies. But it is impossible to diagnose without seeing the Maven and compiler output, and probably the POM file as well.

Comment: Also try doing the Maven build from the command line.

Comment: I was missing project's maven nature.Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by Right click project > Configure > `Convert to Maven Project`.